# Understanding the Bachet's game competition problem

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, game-theory

In lectures we were just solving the following problem :

So we have n stones and a set S that has given positive natural numbers. Two players take stones from the n stone pile and the one who takes the last stones wins the game. We need to find an algorithm that will tell us who wins it. (The number 1 is never in the set S). Players can only take the number of stones that they choose from set S.

So we have two players Stan and Ollie, where Stan always starts. We also have a set of numbers that never has $1$ in it, but it can have other numbers (that are picked by the program).

First we set all the elements in a list to False.

In the following code, the `sequence` is the set of moves that any of the two players can make. The `i` is the index from 1 to the number of stones  which is n. However I do not understand how such a simple loop can solve such a problem. Can somebody explain the theory behind it, why does it work in such a way ?

```
wins=[False]
    i=1
    while i<=n:
        for s in sequence:
            if s>i:
                wins.append(False)
                break
            if not wins[i-s]:
                wins.append(True)
                break
        else:
            wins.append(False)
        i+=1
    if wins[-1]:
        print 'Stan wins'
    else:
        print 'Ollie wins'
```

So how I understand it is, that we have a list that has only `False` in it, and then if the index of stones is bigger than any of the moves(in the above code as `s`) we can make, then we say `True` for that index if the index that is on `i-s` is `False`. So in the end we get a list of `True` and `False` that is `n` long.

Can somebody explain the theory behind this, because I clearly do not understand it. I also found numerous solutions and all use the same technique.

Comment: It's better if you write out the problem here, instead of asking users to go offsite to see it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited

Comment: Stan (first player) wins (`True`) if he can, using one of available moves, reach and then pass a losing position to the second player (`False`), otherwise he himself has a losing position. The `for s in sequence:` simply checks for every available move, if it is a losing position that can be passed (`not wins[i-s]` aka `not False` equals `True`). If there is no such move, then he himself holds a losing move (`else: wins.append(False)`).

Comment: @Vepir Do you maybe know how to make the program faster, since it takes a lot of computational time because of the double loop ?

Comment: @VLC I haven't thought about it, but there are many solutions to this problem already submitted everywhere so you can try to look at those (for example, search *"Bachet's game github"*). Also notice that the wins sequence becomes periodic, so you could find out the solution to very large $n$ by reducing it modulo some period (depending on sequence set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the example $S=\{2,3\}$ to explain.

Think about if you were trying to solve the game with paper and pencil. A good method is to solve the game for smaller pile sizes first. Obviously, the game is a win for Ollie when $n\in\{0,1\}$, since no moves are available, and it is a win for Stan when $n\in \{2,3\}$ since he can win in one move. We summarize the results so far in a table:

| n | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Outcome | O | O | S | S |  |  |

Now, how do we determine the outcome for $n=4$? Consider the options available; from $4$, Stan can either remove $2$ and leave $2$, or remove $3$ and leave $1$. Obviously, removing $3$ is a winning move, so $4$ is a win for Stan. To make the logic crystal clear: *$4$ should be labeled $S$ because it can reach a position which is labeled $O$*.

Now, move on to $n=5$. This time, both options are to positions with $2$ and $3$ stones, which are both labeled $S$. Therefore, $5$ should be marked $O$.

The piece of code you have is doing exactly what we are doing in this post. The list `wins` represents this table, where `False` means Ollie wins and `True` means Stan wins. You check all available options from a position; if at least one is a win for Ollie, then that position is a win for Stan, and if all options are wins for Stan, the position is a win for Ollie.

Comment: So if I understand correctly let me try to explain myself for $n = 6$:

we first see that $2$ and $3$ are less than $6$, so this first might indicate that Stan might win. Then we take a look at the previous winning positions, and we take a look at position $n = 6 - 2$ and the position $n = 6 -3$ and we see that in both positions Stan won, which indicates that in the $n = 6$ position Stan cannot win. So to generalize, if we have $x_1, x_2, x_3,...,x_n$ positions and we have $n+1$ stones, then if n+1 - ($\exists a \in S$) = win_for_player1 $\implies$ win_for_player_2 in the entire game.

Comment: Or basically where True is, that's where the player whose turn is wins

Comment: Do you maybe know how to make the program faster, since it takes a lot of computational time because of the double loop ?

Comment: @VLC Probability not. One idea: you can prove that the sequences of $S$'s and $O$'s will be eventually periodic (like decimal expansions of rational numbers). Therefore, you can first find the repeating pattern, then quickly determine the outcome since can just reduce $n$ modulo the period length. The computational complexity would be something like $2^{\max(S)}\cdot \log n$, so this is only better than your algorithms runtime of $n\cdot |S|$ if the numbers in $S$ are not too large, and if $n$ is quite large.